# What is the best way to enter a code block on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, code-formatting

It's really annoying to insert 4 spaces manually for entering code into the text box.

I am wondering if there is a better method, as found normally in forums (like code tags).

Comment: I write in a text editor (Sublime Text), then copy to web browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select the lines you want as code; press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>; or click the code button

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Select code, click {} button above the text area.

Answer (score 0):

Type or copy paste in your code, highlight the block that you want to display as `code`, then just hit Ctrl + K and it will automatically indent it etc :)

Answer (score -4):

There is one more method and that is to put you code between two backticks.

Comment: Anybody who has negate the answer go through this link (http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) on SO and give a bit attention to Code and Performated Text part.

Comment: That is for inline code spans, not for large code blocks.

Comment: I believe the question is about code not about large code.

Comment: Generally a "block" of code means a large piece of code.

Comment: Also, *"It's really annoying to insert 4 spaces manually"* surely refers to code blocks, not to inline code.